# When the Fourier transform is in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Tags: fourier-transform

When is the Fourier transform of a function in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?
I only know that if $f$ is a Schwartz function, then $\widehat{f}$ It is also a function of Schwartz and therefore, it is in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ function,  but asking that a function be Schwartz is a very strong assumption

Comment: I think any answer to this is not elementary: after proving the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, that $L^1$ maps to continuous functions going to $0$ at infinity, soon after we prove that, among the immediate consequences of the Baire Category theorem (Open Mapping, Closed Graph, Uniform Boundedness), that map is _not_ surjective. In particular, continuous functions going to $0$ at infinity map by FT to a larger space than $L^1$. That's all I know, so this is not answering your question, only explaining that it seems not elementary.

Comment: As Professor Garrett pointed out, it is nontrivial to give an intrinsic description of the set of all functions $f$ with $\hat{f}\in L^1$. Although this may look like cheating, by Parseval's theorem $\hat{f}\in L^1$ iff $f=g*h$ for two $g,h\in L^2$.